Howto write replaceRoot and mergeObjects after lookup in Spring Framework 6 Aggregation
I am writing an Aggregation pipeline in Spring data mongodb core.
After my lookup aggregation, I want to add a replaceRoot stage, but an unsure howto write it in Spring aggregation format.
Working mongo shell stage:
{ $replaceRoot: {'newRoot': {'$mergeObjects': [{'$arrayElemAt': ['$joined',0]},'$$ROOT']}}}

My first attempt but something not right:
Aggregation.replaceRoot().withValueOf(ArithmeticOperators.arrayElementAt(ArrayOperators.Size.lengthOfArray("joined").arrayOfLength(1),0).and("$$ROOT").mergeObjects())


You can try with a simpler approach. That is, using two pipeline stages - first use a projection (e.g., $addFields) to perform the $mergeObjects. Next, the $replaceRoot stage. This will allow to verify that each stage has a result and any error messages - hence easy to debug.

That said, it generally helps to specify the versions of software / database you are working with in your question post.

To add a $replaceRoot stage in Spring Data MongoDB aggregation, you can use the Aggregation.replaceRoot method. Here's how you can translate your MongoDB shell stage to the Spring Data MongoDB aggregation format:

Use Aggregation.replaceRoot to create the $replaceRoot stage.
Use ArrayOperators.ArrayElemAt to get the first element of the joined array.
Use AggregationExpressions.MergeObjects to merge the first element of the joined array with the root document.

Here is the code in Spring Data MongoDB aggregation format:
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Aggregation;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.ArrayOperators;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.AggregationExpressions;

Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
    // other stages...
    Aggregation.replaceRoot().withValue(
        AggregationExpressions.MergeObjects.merge(
            ArrayOperators.ArrayElemAt.arrayOf("joined").elementAt(0),
            Aggregation.ROOT
        )
    )
);

This code creates an aggregation pipeline with a $replaceRoot stage that merges the first element of the joined array with the root document.

Gibbs thanks for the great looking solution. But Im using spring-data-mongodb:4.3.5 and I dont find AggregationExpressions available. There is AggregationExpression though It doesnt contain MergeObjects.  Seems maybe I need to use ObjectOperators.MergeObjects ?
